# How to customized the grand total field with different calculation

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have a dataset in time formation need to perform average calculation. Im using the DevExpress.Web.ASPxPivotGrid.PivotGridCustomSummaryEventArgs to do the calculation.
The Presenting Time & Packing Time is from dataset, Total Service Time = Presenting Time + Packing Time, Total Average Service Time = Total Service Time / Transaction Count

Due to this calculation the grand total for the Total Average Service Time field is not the sum of each row. It will using the formula above and apply to the grand total field of Total Average Service Time field.

I have try to use some method such as store the data in a session, but the data will loop several time and cause the data not accurate.

Image 1 is showing how does the Presenting Time and Packing Time data looks like in row area

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjx7w.png)

Image 2 is showing how does the Presenting Time and Packing Time data looks like in data area

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NR9in.png)

How to customize the calculation of the grand total?